# Newsletter and registration on iphone

Tags: iphone, newsletter

I'd like to know if it was possible, if a user wishes to subscribe to updates of my applications, take a form that is automatically subscribed to this newsletter at this address http://www.gseo.it/lists/?p=subscribe&id=2 (this is my mailing list with double opt in) but I'd like to know that a user can subscibe this newsletter directly from my iphone app.

Thanks

Comment: Why should anybody want this? If an update is available iTunes (or the app store app) will tell.

Answer (score 0):

You could do an HTTP POST to that form using ASIFormDataRequest.

This isn't working code, but it might look something like:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.gseo.it/lists/?p=subscribe&id=2"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"someone@example.com" forKey:@"email"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

You can get the library [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can, open up a UIWebview with the the url provided. Don't forget that this may look not good in the iphone browser so providing a custom html code depending on the user agent may improve things.